# pass function to Angular event handling rootScope.on

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

I got this event :

```
app.run(function($rootScope){

document.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
if (e.keyCode ===13){
$rootScope.$broadcast("EnterPressed",e.target);
}

})

})
```

I want to trigger that event by this command in my controller:

```
$scope.$on('EnterPressed',console.log("pressed enter");
```

if I run the code above, when the paged refreshed I can see the "pressed enter" message on console

but when Im do it Like this :

```
   $scope.$on('EnterPressed',function(){console.log("pressed enter")};
```

the code runs only when enter is pressed.

what is the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.$on` expect as second parameter a function pointer, if you write `console.log("pressed enter")` -> then this isn't a function pointer . It's already a function call.

```
$scope.$on('EnterPressed',console.log("pressed enter"));
```

At this time `console.log("pressed enter")` is already processed to calculate the parameter value (is undefined here).

Your second example is the right way to get this event

```
 $scope.$on('EnterPressed',function(){console.log("pressed enter")};
```

Because you just use a function pointer as parameter.

Comment: Thank you ! Its helped for me

Comment: So choose your winner ;)

Answer (score 0):

In first case that's happen because expression `console.log("pressed enter")` evaluated once time when page is loading.

Function `console.log` with any arguments return `undefined`. So `$scope.$on('EnterPressed',console.log("pressed enter"));` is equivalent of `$scope.$on('EnterPressed',undefined);` with side effect of printing `"pressed enter"` to console.

In second case you pass a callback function to `console.log` and this function still not called. When event is emited `$scope.$on` calls passed function.

To understand this you must see difference between this two expressions:

```
// passed the function:
$scope.$on('EnterPressed', function(){ console.log("pressed enter") });

// passed result of the function:
$scope.$on('EnterPressed', function(){ console.log("pressed enter") }());
```

Comment: Thank you ! Its helped for me too :)